Getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 8 for my adapter code
My logcat looks like:
logcat for app crash
  class ChatAdapter(private val currentUserId: Int) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private val messages = mutableListOf<Message>()
    private var isTypingIndicatorVisible = false

    fun updateMessages(newMessages: List<Message>) {
        messages.addAll(newMessages)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    private val MESSAGE_SENT = 1
    private val MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2
    private val TYPING_INDICATOR = 3

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            MESSAGE_SENT -> {
                val binding = ItemMessageSentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
                SentMessageViewHolder(binding)
            }
            MESSAGE_RECEIVED -> {
                val binding = ItemMessageReceivedBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
                ReceivedMessageViewHolder(binding)
            }
            TYPING_INDICATOR -> {
                val binding = ItemTypingIndicatorBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
                TypingIndicatorViewHolder(binding)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val message = messages[position]
        when (holder.itemViewType) {
            MESSAGE_SENT -> {
                (holder as SentMessageViewHolder).bind(message)
            }
            MESSAGE_RECEIVED -> {
                (holder as ReceivedMessageViewHolder).bind(message)
            }
            TYPING_INDICATOR -> {
                (holder as TypingIndicatorViewHolder).bind(message)
            }
        }
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messages.size + if (isTypingIndicatorVisible) 1 else 0
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val message = messages[position]
        return if (isTypingIndicatorVisible && position == messages.size) {
            TYPING_INDICATOR
        } else if (message.senderEmail == currentUserId.toString()) {
            MESSAGE_SENT
        } else {
            MESSAGE_RECEIVED
        }
    }

    fun showTypingIndicator(isVisible: Boolean) {
        isTypingIndicatorVisible = isVisible
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class TypingIndicatorViewHolder(private val binding: ItemTypingIndicatorBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(message: Message) {
            binding.tvTyping.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
    inner class SentMessageViewHolder(private val binding: ItemMessageSentBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(message: Message) {
            binding.tvMsgSent.text = message.content
            val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
            val date = dateFormat.parse(message.date)
            binding.tvDateTime.text = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(date)
        }
    }

    inner class ReceivedMessageViewHolder(private val binding: ItemMessageReceivedBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(message: Message) {
            binding.tvMsgReceived.text = message.content
            val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
            val date = dateFormat.parse(message.date)
            binding.tvDateTime.text = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(date)
        }
    }
}

This is my adapter code for a chat screen. I am using 3 viewtypes for sending message, receiving message, and showing typing indicator.
The activity works fine but when I open keyboard and type something it crashes with the error I mentioned in logcat screenshot.
I tried changing the getITemViewType and getItemCount logic.
And the solutions provided on stackOverFlow for IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Why do you have this logic in your getItemCount method? return messages.size + if (isTypingIndicatorVisible) 1 else 0. This is what is causing the indexOutOfBounds exception.

Here you are accessing messages[position] BEFORE checking position == messages.size. When position does equal messages.size, message[position] throws.
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val message = messages[position]
        return if (isTypingIndicatorVisible && position == messages.size) {
            TYPING_INDICATOR
        } else if (message.senderEmail == currentUserId.toString()) {
            MESSAGE_SENT
        } else {
            MESSAGE_RECEIVED
        }
    }

The solution is to check messages.size first.
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (isTypingIndicatorVisible && position == messages.size) {
            TYPING_INDICATOR
        } else {
            val message = messages[position]
            if (message.senderEmail == currentUserId.toString()) {
                MESSAGE_SENT
            } else {
                MESSAGE_RECEIVED
            }
        }
    }

Or make use of nullable if you find the nested indentation hurts your eyes
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val message = messages.getOrNull[position]
        return if (isTypingIndicatorVisible && message == null) {
            TYPING_INDICATOR
        } else if (message?.senderEmail == currentUserId.toString()) {
            MESSAGE_SENT
        } else {
            MESSAGE_RECEIVED
        }
    }


Below line from your code is throwing the exception you need to check length

val message = messages[position]

Use Condition below:
if(position < messages.length) { 
     //Other_types logic goes here
} else if (isTypingIndicatorVisible && message == null){
   return TYPING_INDICATOR
}

